# Limit MKMapView cache size

Tags: ios, caching, mkmapview

I have a MapView which is a singleton I reuse in many different views. As a consequence, this instance's cache will build up each time I show a new location.

At a certain point, the device will send a memory warning, and that's the time when I should clear the map's cache. That point, however, comes after the map has way too much data cached, being that most of it probably won't be shown again.

I would like to know if it is possible to limit the cache size, so the memory usage won't increase too much and I can have a better control of it, and perhaps even tweaking different values for different device models.

If setting a limit is not possible, is there a way to read the app's memory consumption? Then I could manually clear the cache if it's above a certain value I choose.

To clear the cache I am using the trick of switching map types:

```
- (void)clearMapCache {
  MKMapType type = [self mapType];
  [self setMapType:(type + 1) % 3];
  [self setMapType:type];
}
```